# Thunderbird - error sending email to Gmail address?

Tags: email, gmail, thunderbird

Just when i need to send urgent email messages I get this error

```
An error occurred while sending mail. The mail server responded:  5.7.0 This message was blocked because its content presents a potential
5.7.0 security issue. Please visit
5.7.0  https://support.google.com/mail/answer/6590 to review our message
5.7.0 content and attachment content guidelines. o4sm36723619wjd.15 - gsmtp. Please check the message and try again.
```

Client: thunderbird

Sending email from @hotmail to @gmail recipient

my message does not contain  does not contain attachment.
message contains dropbox URL and my signature with few images

I use this email address for 7 years maybe and never has these problems. Any idea what could be wrong ?